# I am not able to print character U+0103 from UNICODE Latin Extended-A

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

I am not able to print the UNICODE character U+0103 when that character is part of a string added to a listbox

this is a character after the first 256 of UNICODE, more exactly U+0103 is the 259th character according to

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

```
TCHAR szBuffer[_CVTBUFSIZE];
swprintf_s(szBuffer, _CVTBUFSIZE, TEXT("rom\u00e2n\u0103"));
MessageBox(NULL, szBuffer, NULL, NULL);
```

works correctly, but if I add szBuffer to a listbox

```
SendMessage(hLanguages, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)szBuffer);
```

writes correctly the U+00e2 character but the next one U+0103 is not OK

Comment: Given that there is no length parameter, I assume it is going to look for a NULL byte to know where the end of the string is.  Given the encoding of that first byte, it probably sees `{0xe2, 0x00 /*stop */}`.

Comment: @AutomaticInvest_4,  "writes correctly the U+00e2 character but the next one U+0103 is not OK" --> what about the `n` in between.  Is that printed?  Given `"rom\u00e2n\u0103"`, `n` is the next character after U+00e2, not U+0103.

Comment: yes, 'n' between is OK in both places (MessageBox and listbox)..also if I add a new character say A to the end like swprintf_s(szBuffer, _CVTBUFSIZE, TEXT("rom\u00e2n\u0103A")); the last A is also OK both in the MessageBox and in the listbox

Comment: What happens with other characters above U+00FF?

Comment: instead of a character above 'U+00FF' I see something like '|'

Comment: Is the `_UNICODE` macro defined? I don't know why people bother with `TCHAR` these days.

Comment: I think so..since I compile with project properties "Use UNICODE Character Set" at project properties (general properties section)

Comment: Don't use `TCHAR` in modern coding! Do you have the same problem if you use Unicode explicitly for everyhing? `WCHAR szBuffer[_CVTBUFSIZE]; wcscpy_s(szBuffer, _CVTBUFSIZE, L"română");
MessageBoxW(NULL, szBuffer, NULL, NULL); SendMessageW(hLanguages, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)szBuffer);` Are you creating the ListBox using `CreateWindow(Ex)W()`? Does `IsWindowUnicode()` return TRUE for the ListBox?

Comment: a screenshot for MessageBox https://drive.google.com/file/d/10q_D-1Fh48l2ErBJGHGtFga3Hx4F626e/view?usp=sharing; and a screenshot for listbox https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zy4wPNPcxunQKjE2OHY6KUYEhV04nMoP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in the meantime the next Unicode character after 0x00e2 which is 0x00e3 is an acceptable substitute for 0x0103..

Comment: @RemyLebeau The character set used by a window is determined when the window class is registered. I don't think you can create a common control for which `IsWindowUnicode` returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set another font for listbox. For example:

```
HFONT font = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
SendMessage(listboxHWND, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font, TRUE);
```

Lisbox probably displays 'box' for not defined glyph which looks like letter I.

Or to get font similar to the one used in message box.

```
NONCLIENTMETRICS    ncm = {};
ncm.cbSize = sizeof(ncm);

if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, 0, &ncm, 0))
{
    HFONT font = (HFONT)CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
    SendMessage(listboxHWND, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font, TRUE);
}
```